# Optimize search in SwiftUI to load without lagging

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, contacts

What will be the best way to optimize this swift code to filter without lagging. I have tried both appending and binding but still, it lags.

```
import Contacts
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ContactStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var contacts: [ContactsModel] = []
    
    var searchText: String = ""{
        didSet {
            self.fetchContacts()
        }
    }
    
    
    init() {
        self.fetchContacts()
    }
    
    
    private func fetchContacts() {
        let store = CNContactStore()
        store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (granted, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("failed to request access", error)
                return
            }
            if granted {
                //                print("access granted")
                
                let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactBirthdayKey]
                let keysToFetch = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey] as [CNKeyDescriptor]
                let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])
                do {
                    if self.searchText.isEmpty {
                        try store.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { (contact, stopPointer) in
                            self.contacts.append(ContactsModel(firstName: contact.givenName, lastName: contact.familyName, birthDay: contact.birthday?.date ?? Date(timeInterval: -3600, since: Date()) , telephone: contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue ?? ""))
                        })
                    } else {
                        self.contacts = []
                        let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContacts(matchingName: self.searchText)
                        let contacts = try store.unifiedContacts(matching: predicate, keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
                        print(contacts)
                        for i in contacts{
                            self.contacts = [ContactsModel(firstName: i.givenName, lastName: i.familyName, telephone: i.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue ?? "")]
                            //                            self.contacts.append(ContactsModel(firstName: i.givenName, lastName: i.familyName, telephone: i.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue ?? ""))
                            
                        }
                    }
                } catch let error {
                    print("Failed to enumerate contact", error)
                }
            } else {
                print("access denied")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `searchText` as a `@Published` var. Then use Combine to subscribe to, adding a `debounce`. In this way, you can limit the frequency of execution of the fetch request.

It would be something like this

```
$searchText
  .debounce(for: 5, scheduler: RunLoop.main) //5 seconds debounce
  .sink(
    receiveValue: { 
      self.fetchContacts()
    }
  )
  .store(in: &disposables)
```